# How to create Asynchronous Java Restlet webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, restlet

I am creating **Webservices** in Java using **Restlet API** with Apache Tomcat.

In Restlet webservices are created **Synchronous** by default.

I want to create **Asynchronous** webservice using Restlet. Consider I have **searchCity** webservice, if client sends request **abc** for first time and **abcd** for second time in a quick way, then webservice should give response to each request like how **Google's** search box appears with some suggestions.

Please suggest me how can I implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also have the same problem..answer please

Comment: Async apart, why can't this be achieved via two parallel AJAX requests? One updating the suggestions box, other updating result DIV. Did you see Jetty continuation, servlet 3 specs?

Comment: @Nishant, I am not using Jetty nor servlet, AJAX..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible in Restlet. You may try using resteasy framework.

Comment: hmm, this is a comment at best.

Comment: Hi Raj thanks for your quick reply. But what if I want it to implement  in Restlet?